# purrr::map() not working with rlang::as_label() and/or rlang::ensym()

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, rlang

I want to iterate through a group of dataframes, and one of the values I want to return is the name of the dataframe. I defined a function using `rlang::ensym()` and `rlang::as_label()` that works when applied to a single object, but does not work with `purrr::map()`.

Reproducible example:

```r
function1 <- function(input) {
  return(rlang::as_label(rlang::ensym(input)))
}

input1 <- "a"

function1(input1) ## returns "input1"

output1 <- purrr::map(list(input1), ~function1(.)) 
output1[[1]] ## returns "." want it to return "input1"

output2 <- purrr::map(list(input1), function(x) function1(x)) 
output2[[1]] ## returns "x" want it to return "input1"
```

Comment: Values in list don't have variable names. The list just stores the value, not the original variable name. You can use functions like `tibble::lst(input)` to create a named list which default to naming the list with the original variable name and then use `imap` to iterate over the list and it's names. Lazy evaluation just isn't going to work here with `purrr::map`. Alternatively you could use an `alist` but that's not supercommon. Is stores unresolved values. Like `purrr::map(alist(input1), function1)`